# Can't free linked list in objective-C iPhone dev

Tags: iphone, memory-management, linked-list

I'm writing an application for iPhone, that uses a linked list to keep track of a set of points. I've used linked lists time and time again successfully in other C programs, but I've never used a linked list on iPhone, and my 'freeList' function is crashing.

```
pointNode * temp;

pointTrain = lPoints->next;
while (pointTrain) {
    temp = pointTrain->next;
    free(pointTrain);
    pointTrain = temp;
}
```

This is how I'm freeing my list, 'lPoints' is the head, and is always allocated during runtime. This code is executed before any more nodes are added, but it seems to still execute even though "pointTrain" is NULL, which SHOULD make it skip the while loop. Unfortunately, the loop is still executed, and the program crashes on free(pointTrain)

Is there something I'm just not seeing?

Points are added like so within a loop:

```
pointTrain->x = onPx / trueWidth;
pointTrain->y = onPx % trueWidth;
pointTrain->next = (pointNode*)malloc(sizeof(pointNode));
pointTrain = pointTrain->next;
```

Comment: What is pointNode? A C-Struct, Objective-C Class, or C++ Struct/Class?

Comment: Why don't you use an NSMutableArray or something?

Comment: Obj-C is a strict superset of C. If you've written linked-lists in C they work exactly the same in Objective-C.

Answer (score 4):

A wise man once said, "I'd rather ride a horse the direction it's going."

Don't roll your own struct when there's a perfectly good `NSMutableArray` class you could be using. Linear iteration of an array is cheap and easy, and the class comes with its own memory management hooks, and all you have to do is USE them.

This is something I see a lot with C and C++ devs who pop over to Objective-C. The next project on my plate is to un-fubar a project that a VERY senior C++ guy spent the last six months on. Looking at the code, it's plain that he spent almost all of that time arguing with the framework. He's practically built his *own* framework at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Are you explicitly initializing next to `NULL` or `nil`?

If not, its likely to already be set to some non zero value, and therefore `while (pointTrain)` will still evaluate to true.

Comment: I was just writing a longwinded version of the same answer; malloc makes no guarantees about the contents of any memory returned. A lot of people use calloc or an extra call to bzero as part of their standard pattern for exactly that reason. Beyond that, the Objective-C runtime provided on the iPhone is a strict superset of C and all the normal C rules apply, so the iPhone part of the problem shouldn't really be an issue.